# Proof of intractability of computing the prior distribution in bayesian inference

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference, bayesian, variational-analysis

In this paper: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/epdf/10.1080/01621459.2017.1285773?needAccess=true I do not understand why there are K^n terms in the integral in Equation (9) instead of n^K. If we have n observations, and each observation can belong to one of K clusters, then we should have n^K possible assignments. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Try a small example, say $n=5$ and $K=2$.

Comment: I did, got different numbers, there must be something that I am missing

Comment: There are $K$ ways to assign the first observation to a cluster, $K$ ways to assign the second observation to a cluster, and so on, so it is $K \cdot K \cdots K = K^n$.